# Removed rpm symlink from bin/rpm

Tags: symbolic-link, centos-7, rpm

I have accidentally removed the symlink to `/bin/rpm` from my Centos7 installation. Now the rpm command is not working. Does anyone know how to fix this one or how to add this again as symlink ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/bin/rpm` is typically not a symlink.
There is a symlink `/bin` which points to `/usr/bin` *directory*.

So if you have removed `/bin/rpm` - you have removed an actual file, not a symlink.

For restoring it, you will need access to another CentOS 7 machine, running the same architecture (e.g. x86_64).

Copy it from the other machine by uploading it to the server via SFTP.

Ensure matching version afterward, by running:

```
yum reinstall rpm
```

Comment: Thanks ,
just "yum reinstall rpm" works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall `rpm` (`yum reinstall rpm`, or even `yum reinstall /bin/rpm` -- if you don't know the package's name). The `yum` program uses RPM format and databases, but doesn't run `rpm` itself.

Lucky you. Next time you'll delete something really critical. Be **careful** when running as `root`.